# Wireless adapter missing

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I have a HP ProBook 4520s laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit and a Ralink RT3090 802.11b/g/n wireless. The last few days, I started noticing that I was getting weaker Wi-Fi connections, but this was not much of a problem.

The real issues started two days ago, when I noticed that I can't seem to connect to a network. The wireless has gone missing, and was only found as a hidden device in the Device Manager. Enabling, disabling, didn't work, as well as restarting and installing a million different drivers for it, and then rebooting each time. I also uninstalled the device and tried to reinstall a single driver and restart, it still doesn't work. Furthermore, during this whole ordeal it actually worked for a short time, but after a couple of hours it would stop working and go missing again. Once, Windows found drivers for it itself, another time it said something like "this device is experiencing driver of hardware problems". Basically, the issues are all over the place with my wireless.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The part might be failing.  You could try re-seating it (open it up, remove the wifi module, and put it back).  You could try a replacement if not. http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02487851

Comment: You can also buy an external (USB) WiFi adapter for <US$10, such as http://www.amazon.com/Edimax-EW-7811Un-150Mbps-Raspberry-Supports/dp/B003MTTJOY/. Some advantage: there's no installation and putting it on a USB extension enables moving for best signal.

Comment: Try booting in safe mode with networking.  See what the results are and post back.